# Calling expl3's \use:c on an expression expanding to a cs name causes error

Tags: expl3

any suggestion on how to debug or fix this problem would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \__foo_aux:n #1{\c_novalue_tl}
\cs_set:Npn \__foo:n #1
{
    \cs_set:Npn \__foo_aux:n ##1{#1}
     __foo_aux:n
}

\begin{document}

% For comparison's sake:
\tl_new:N \__bar_tl
\tl_set:Nn \__bar_tl {__foo_aux:n}
\use:c{\__bar_tl}{X} % -No Value-

% The code that generates an error:
\\
\__foo_aux:n{X} % -No Value- %
\\ \__foo:n{(#1)} % __foo_aux:n % 
\\ \__foo_aux:n{X} % (X)
\\ \use:c{\__foo:n{(#1)}}{X} % Expected: (X)
% Console output
%! Missing \endcsname inserted.
%<to be read again> 
%                   \tex_long:D 
%l.22 \\ \use:c{\__foo:n{(#1)}}
%  {X} %! Missing \endcsname inserted.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't do assignments inside the argument of `\use:c`.

Comment: Apparently so. Dead end then?

Comment: It's not really clear what your aim is.

Comment: Have a macro taking one argument, modify the code `\__foo_aux`, return its cs name, and invoke it using `\use:c`. I would have thought preceding `\use:c` by `\exp_args:No`, `Nf` or `Nx` would have eliminated the error, but not. Why not?

Comment: The argument of `\use:c` *must* consist of fully expandable tokens and the final expansion *must* consist of characters only. If something is not expandable, like `\cs_set:Npn` it *cannot* appear there, notwithstanding any usage of `\exp_args:N<whatever>` (which would do nothing to unexpandable tokens).

Comment: Having `\__foo:n`return `\__foo_aux:n` and invoking `\__foo:n{(#1)}}{X}` works, but ... I'll finish this thought later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\cs_new:Npn \__erwann_action:n #1 { \c_novalue_tl }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \erwann_set:n #1 { \cs_set:Npn \__erwann_action:n ##1 { #1 } }
\cs_new:Npn \erwann_do:n #1 { \__erwann_action:n { #1 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \erwann_do:nn #1 #2 { \erwann_set:n { #1 } \erwann_do:n { #2 } }
```

and then use

```
\__erwann_action:n {X} % -No Value-
\erwann_do:n {X} % -No Value-
\erwann_set:n {(#1)} % just setup
\erwann_do:n {X} % (X)
\erwann_do:nn {(#1)} {X} % Expected: (X) OK
```

Comment: Thanks. This post has been cited in this repository: https://github.com/er-cpp/l3erw/tree/master/numbrdcs

Answer (score 2):

The `\use:c` function is just a wrapper around the `\csname` primitive of TeX. The description in the TeXbook is quite clear (page 40):

> Conversely, you can go from a list of character tokens to a
>   control sequence by saying ‘`\csname`⟨tokens⟩`\endcsname`’. The tokens
>   that appear in this construction between `\csname` and `\endcsname` may
>   include other control sequences, as long as those control sequences
>   ultimately expand into characters instead of TeX primitives; the final
>   characters can be of any category, not necessarily letters. For example,
>   ‘`\csname TeX\endcsname`’ is essentially the same as ‘`\TeX`’; but
>   ‘`\csname\TeX\endcsname`’ is illegal, because `\TeX` expands into tokens
>   containing the `\kern` primitive. Furthermore,
>   ‘`\csname\string\TeX\endcsname`’ will produce the unusual control sequence
>   ‘`\\TeX`’, i.e., the token `|\TeX|`, which you can't ordinarily
>   write.

Not only the mentioned `\kern` is illegal, but *any* unexpandable primitive such as `\hbox` or `\def`. Since every assignment is made with unexpandable primitives, no assignment can take place in `\csname...\endcsname` as well as in the argument to `\use:c`.

There may be workarounds, but I can't figure out a situation where you would use that idea.