# expl3: making arguments from a loop

Tags: expl3, loops

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \erw_loop:n #1
{
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
    \int_do_while:nNnn 
        {\l_tmpa_int} < {#1} 
        {
            \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
            {\int_to_Alph:n{\l_tmpa_int}} 
        }
        {}
}


\begin{document}

\use_ii:nnn{A}{B}{C}\\ % B

\erw_loop:n{3}\\ % ABC

\use_ii:nnn\erw_loop:n{3} % 3 % would like B


\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I tried different versions of `\exp_args:` before `\use_ii`, no success. Perhaps you know a way that would work?

Answer (score 3):

As with [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431046) this is an expansion problem.  As indicated by its signature, `\use_ii:nnn` takes three arguments and return the second of those.  In the example

```
\use_ii:nnn\erw_loop:n{3}
```

The first argument is `\erw_loop:n`, the second argument is `3`, and the third is `\ExplSyntaxOff` which is a few lines down, but inside the ExplSyntax region spaces and newlines are ignored.  This results in a pathological situation where you accidentally remove `\ExplSyntaxOff`, but it luckily doesn't do harm because the next statement is `\end{document}`.  What you want is the following

```
\exp_last_unbraced:Nx \use_ii:nnn { \erw_loop:n { 3 } }
```

because this expands to

```
\use_ii:nnn ABC
```

given that `\erw_loop:n { 3 }` is fully expandable, which is also not given in your code.  Not only is `\erw_loop:n` marked as protected which inhibits expansion from the start but it also performs assignments which are never expandable.   Therefore I'd rewrite the body to

```
\int_step_function:nN { #1 } \int_to_Alph:n
```

The function `\int_step_function:nN` is *conditionally expandable*, meaning it is fully expandable if and only if all of its arguments are fully expandable.  Since `#1` has to be expandable anyway (it has to expand to a valid expression, digestible by `\int_eval:n`) and `\int_to_Alph:n` is expandable as well, this is ensured.

Still I think that this not a good way to deal with this.  What if `\erw_loop:n` only returned two tokens?  What if it returned many more than three tokens?  But since the example looks extremely artificial and the use case is not clear to me, I cannot help you there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \erw_loop:n #1
  {
    \int_step_function:nN { #1 } \int_to_Alph:n
  }

\exp_last_unbraced:Nx \use_ii:nnn { \erw_loop:n { 3 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This post has been cited in this repo: https://github.com/er-cpp/l3erw/tree/master/compose